# https Web API call from Windows CE to Windows Azure no longer work

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-webapi

We have some C# code (shown below) running under .NET Compact Framework 3.5 of a Windows CE device that used to work (still work in April 2018) and allowed us to make https call to our Web API created by ASP.NET Core 2.0 and hosted with Windows Azure's Web App. However, at some point, we don't know exactly when (after August 2018 for sure), the same code from Windows CE is not able to make https call to the https Web API from Windows Azure anymore. It started to return exception "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" for some reasons.

I guess there must be some changes from the Azure Web App side doesn't allow https call from CE device although it works fine for the https call from PC's browsers.

```
private void CallHTTPSWebApi()
{
string fullURI = "https://<our api url>";
req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullURI);
req.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
req.Method = "GET";


    try
    {
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

    ResponseStatusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode;

    using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine("Response Result = " + result);

    }
    response.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception : " + ex.Message);
    }

}
```

I have tried implementing our own ICretificatePolicy to accept all the certificates validation from the ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy property as shown below. However, it still get the same exception.

```
public class AcceptAllCertificatePolicy : ICertificatePolicy
{
    public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate
    certificate, WebRequest request, int certificateProblem)
    {
        // Just accept.
        return true;
    }
}
```

Before creating the WebRequest, I inserted the line.

```
ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new AcceptAllCertificatePolicy();
```

So, is there any setting or configuration from Windows Azure site I can try to accept the https call from CE code shown?

Comment: I bet that it is connected with TLS version (something like compact .Net is using old 1.0-1.1 which is disabled on Azure)

Comment: Thanks Selvin! I have set Minimum TLS Version to 1.0 in Azure but still have the same exception. Also, tested the same code in Desktop's .NET framework from PC, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot to put these two lines for my variables declaration.

Comment: private HttpWebRequest req;  private HttpStatusCode ResponseStatusCode { get; set; }

Comment: In your shoes I would dig on Google with TSL version, sni-ssl/ip-ssl, legacy ssl with azure.... Also are you sure that changes are deployed immediately?

Comment: In fact, I set the Minimum TLS Version to 1.0 long time ago. I'm pretty sure they are effective.